# Почему не выполняется метод constructor в react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Подскажите, почему constructor не выполняется в REACT NATIVE? 
Определяю в конструкторе this.state, но в методе render state пуст. При выполнении следующего кода получаю ошибку "Cannot read property 'text' of null".

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: 'Hello world!'
    }
  }
  render() {
    let text = this.state.text;
    return (
      <View >
        <Text>{ text }</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Comment: А setter-то там есть? Обычно setState рекомендуют использовать.

Comment: Попробуйте `state`  изменить на любое другое слово,например `aaa` =>  `this.aaa = {...}`

Comment: Изменил имя свойства state на foo и понял что надо было всего лишь  перезагрузить приложение ибо состояние компонента не обновляется при hot reload. Спасибо за совет

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan  оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ